# If $f$ is an even function and for $a \gt 0$, $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)=L_a$, then for $b=-a$, $\lim_{y \to b}f(y)=L_a$

Tags: limits, solution-verification

This is a fairly intuitive claim, but there was one step (where I defined my $\delta$) I took in its proof that looked a little funny. I'll mark it with a $\dagger$. Any input is appreciated.

---

> If $f$ is an even function and for $a \gt 0$, $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a}f(x)=L_a$, then for $b=-a$, $\displaystyle \lim_{y \to b}f(y)=L_a$.

By assumption, we know that for an arbitrary $\varepsilon$, we have $\delta_{\varepsilon}$ such that for any $x$: $|x-a| \lt \delta_{\varepsilon} \rightarrow |f(x)-L_a| \lt \varepsilon$. Let $\delta^*=\min(\delta_{\varepsilon},a)\quad$ ($\dagger$). Now, for any $y$ that satisfies $|y - b| \lt \delta^*$, we first note $y \lt 0$. It follows that for some $x \gt 0$:

\begin{align}
|y-b| &= |-x -(-a)| \text{ where } -x=y \text{ and } -a=b\\
&=|-x+a| \\
&=|x-a| \\
\end{align}

Since $|y-b| \lt \delta^*,$ we have $|x-a| \lt \delta^*$, which means $|x-a| \lt \delta_{\varepsilon}$. By our initial assumption, we then have $|f(x)-L_a|\lt \varepsilon$. Because $f$ is even, we know $f(x)=f(-x)$, which gives: $|f(-x)-L_a|\lt \varepsilon$. Recalling that $-x=y$, we have shown: $|f(y) - L_a| \lt \varepsilon$ and conclude with:

$$|y-b| \lt \delta^* \rightarrow |f(y)-L_a| \lt \varepsilon$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That “funny” step is not needed, one can use the same $\delta$.

If $\epsilon > 0$ and $\delta > 0$ are such that
$$
 |x-a| < \delta \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon
$$
then for all $y$ with $|y - b| < \delta$
$$
|(-y) - a| = |y+a| = |y-b| < \delta
$$
and therefore
$$
 |f(y) - L| = |f(-y) - L| < \epsilon \, .
$$